# wso2 message soap format conversion

Tags: soap, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I use wso2 4.8.1,  I have trouble with soap out messages from wso2 esb. Mesages are in soap 1.2 format 1.2 my client software expect soap messages in 1.1 format.

In my sequence file, I force soap format using the following section :

```
<send>
  <endpoint>
    <default format="soap12"/>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

This works fine on one of my servers, but it doesn't work on the other :

- It works well on Windows XP with Java 1.6.0_13
- It does not work on Windows 7 with Java 1.6.0_30

That's the only differences !

Notice that I use Axis2_pt.xml configuration file (pass through) for Axis2.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **messageType** property :

soap1.1 : `<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>`

soap1.2 : `<property name="messageType" value="application/soap+xml" scope="axis2"/>`

with soap1.1, you need to set the SOAP Action : use `<header name="Action" value="mySoapAction"/>`